# Select latest month record from group of records for several groups

Tags: sql, group-by, max, cascading

I have a table that generates a record each month for each project status report (PSR) if a PSR is/was generated. From a single table, I need to get the most recent record for each PSR.

This gives me the list of PSR's I am looking for:

```
SELECT Max(Main.PSRMonth) AS MaxOfPSRMonth, Main.PE, Main.Loc, Main.EWO
FROM Main
GROUP BY Main.PE, Main.Loc, Main.EWO
ORDER BY Main.PE, Main.Loc, Main.EWO;

Table:Main 
Primary Key is PSRMonth + PE + EWO + LOC
```

Now, I need all fields `FROM Main` based on the selection above.
I would like to do this with one SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

> I need all fields FROM Main based on the selection above.

Then try this:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM Main m1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
      Max(PSRMonth) AS MaxOfPSRMonth, 
      PE, 
      Loc, 
      EWO
    FROM Main 
    GROUP BY PE, Loc, EWO 
) m2 ON  m1.PE = m2.PE AND m1.Loc = m2.Loc AND m1.EWO = m2.EWO 
     AND m1.PSRMonth = m2.MaxOfPSRMonth
ORDER BY m1.PE, M1.Loc, M1.EWO;
```